# Latin square code dimension

Tags: matrices, coding-theory, latin-square

I am need to understand what is the dimension of the code generated by the Olderogge Encoding:

Given two mutually orthogonal latin squares, the encoding of a message of $m^2$ bits is:

- the message itself ($m^2$ bits);
- the parity checks of the rows of the matrix $M$ having $m$ rows and $m$ columns obtained by partitioning the original message ($m$ bits);
- the parity checks of the columns of $M$ ($m$ bits);
- the parity checks of the rows of the matrix obtained remapping $M$ using the MOLS - let it be $N$ ($m$ bits);
- the parity checks of the columns of $N$ ($m$ bits);
- an overall parity bit.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The dimension of the code is surely $k=m^2$. Looks like $4m+1$ parity check bits were added, so the length of the code would be $n=m^2+4m+1$. I'm not familiar with the construction, so cannot tell for sure if I missed something. How exactly is the remapping done? First generate a magic square using the two MOLs, and reposition the information bits accordingly? Or what?

Comment: Mapping: if you denote $n_{i,j}$ with $n\left(i,j\right)$ and the elements of $M$ accordingly, the mapping is:

$n\left(i,j\right)=m\left(a\left(i,j\right),b\left(i,j\right)\right)$